# mjpg-streamer-experimental error

Tags: camera

`pi@raspberrypi:~ $ /usr/local/bin/mjpg_streamer -i "input_uvc.so -r 1280x720 -d /dev/video0 -f 15 -q 80" -o "output_http.so -p 8080 -w /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www"`

MJPG Streamer Version: git rev: f387bb44e6c087271b763b27da998bf2e06c4f5d

i: Using V4L2 device.: /dev/video0

i: Desired Resolution: 1280 x 720

i: Frames Per Second.: 15

i: Format............: JPEG

i: TV-Norm...........: DEFAULT

i: The specified resolution is unavailable, using: width 640 height 480 instead

i: Could not obtain the requested pixelformat: MJPG , driver gave us: YUYV

```
... will try to handle this by checking against supported formats.
```

... Falling back to YUV mode (consider using -yuv option). Note that this

requires much more CPU power

UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error at Pan (relative): Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error at Tilt (relative): Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error at Pan Reset: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error at Tilt Reset: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error at Pan/tilt Reset: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_ADD - Error at Focus (absolute): Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at Pan (relative): Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at Tilt (relative): Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at Pan Reset: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at Tilt Reset: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at Pan/tilt Reset: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at Focus (absolute): Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at LED1 Mode: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at LED1 Frequency: Inappropriate ioctl for device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at Disable video processing: Inappropriate ioctl for

device (25)

UVCIOC_CTRL_MAP - Error at Raw bits per pixel: Inappropriate ioctl for device

(25)

o: www-folder-path......: /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www/

o: HTTP TCP port........: 8080

o: HTTP Listen Address..: (null)

o: username:password....: disabled

o: commands.............: enabled

### What's the problem?

I need help!

Comment: The formatting on this makes it almost impossible to read.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error per se. Your camera just does not support fancy features that `mjpeg-streamer` provides. `mjpeg-streamer` was primarily built to stream images from USB-WebCams that provide images as compressed JPEG (an Motion-JPEG stream hence MJPG) and camera movements.

Your WebCam obviously does not provide images in JPEG but YUVU, which is a raw sensor format. Therefore your Pi has to do the heavy lifting and convert the image into JPEG and create an Motion-JPEG stream out of it.

This does not take any advantage of the Raspberry Pi's hardware JPEG encoding capabilities. In my case this uses one complete core on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. Therefore I've written some program that does basically the same as `mjpeg-streamer` but that takes advantage of the hardware JPEG encoder to reduce the load on the CPU.

I've called it `PICS` **P**i **I**mproved **C**amera **S**treaming and you can find it on [github](https://github.com/kwasmich/PICS). This reduces the CPU usage to about 1/10th of a Pi 2 core.
Another improvement is that the camera is being turned off if noone is watching the stream. This feels much better if your camera has an inicator light. With `mjpeg-streamer` your camera is constantly on and the image data just gets wasted and also wastes-power.

Comment: Which camera is better to use for this?

Comment: I don't own a pan and tilt MJPG capable camera myself. So I can't give a recommendation. But according to your post your webcam should at least work so what are you missing that you want another camera?

Comment: How build PICS?
sudo apt install libjpeg9-dev
and what's next?

Comment: Run make inside the cloned git repo.

Comment: I build PICS. How use raspberry camera and how open localhost:10000

Comment: Well, just like you would do with mjpeg-streamer: open the stream in your favorite browser. If you use a remote machine, then you will have to replace localhost with the hostname of your pi. Optionally you can use the IP address.